# Aggregate from one document array to another

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to do a transformation from one data structure to another and am using NoSQL Booster as I feel more comfortable using SQL queries than I do using Mongo script, a little lazy but its worked for me thus far.

I have a document which has a an array of line items which represents a sales receipt. The line items are the items sold.

I have used the following SQL query to generate Mongo script to select and then rename values from one document to create another. Where I'm stuck is in selecting from an array some fields and renaming them into a new document within a new array.

```
mb.runSQLQuery(`

   SELECT   object_origin, 
            party_uuid AS company,
            connection_uuid AS connection,
            object_created AS object_creation_date,
            "object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date" AS transaction_date,
            "object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.total_price"
            + "object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.total_tax" AS transaction_gross_value,
            "object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.total_price" AS transaction_net_value,
            'goods-service-transaction' AS object_class,
            'point-of-sale' AS object_origin_category,
            'offline' AS object_origin_type,
            object_origin AS object_origin,
            "object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.invoice_number" AS transaction_reference,
            "object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.status" AS transaction_status,
            'GBP' AS transaction_currency,
            "object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_products.name" AS 'line_items.item_name'

   FROM Vend_raw_transactions

`)
```

The query above works all except the last line which creates an object in the document called line_items but it isn't an array. The source is also an array.

Below is the Mongo script it creates for me:

```
  db.Vend_raw_transactions.aggregate(
[{
  "$project": {
    "object_origin": "$object_origin",
    "company": "$party_uuid",
    "connection": "$connection_uuid",
    "object_creation_date": "$object_created",
    "transaction_date": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date",
    "transaction_gross_value": {
      "$add": [
        "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.total_price",
        "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.total_tax"
      ]
    },
    "transaction_net_value": 
"$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.total_price",
    "object_class": "goods-service-transaction",
    "object_origin_category": "point-of-sale",
    "object_origin_type": "offline",
    "transaction_reference": 
"$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.invoice_number",
    "transaction_status": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.status",
    "transaction_currency": "GBP",
    "line_items.item_name": 
"$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_products.name"
 }
}])
```

Does anyone know why the last line isn't working for me?

```
"line_items.item_name": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_products.name"
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing an [*] somewhere. Thanks, Matt

EDITED TO ADD example of Vend Transaction

```
{ 
"object_category" : "application", 
"object_type" : "register-sales-24-months", 
"object_origin" : "vend", 
"tenant_uuid" : "00000000-0000-0009-9999-999999999999", 
"party_uuid" : "8d519765-05d2-469f-ad35-d7a22fa9df2f", 
"subscription_uuid" : "0", 
"connection_uuid" : "6ed9bd79-d9c5-4296-a821-7e15b1c69e6c", 
"status" : "", 
"object_created" : ISODate("2018-03-15T21:40:57.158+0000"), 
"object_raw_origin_data" : {
    "pagination" : {
        "results" : NumberInt(75964), 
        "page" : NumberInt(1), 
        "page_size" : NumberInt(200), 
        "pages" : NumberInt(380)
    }, 
    "register_sales" : {
        "id" : "776a66f2-993c-b372-11e8-26f9bbe253f4", 
        "source" : "USER", 
        "source_id" : "", 
        "register_id" : "02dcd191-ae55-11e6-edd8-ec8dce1d9e1c", 
        "market_id" : "3", 
        "customer_id" : "02d59481-b67d-11e5-f667-b08185e8f6d5", 
        "customer_name" : "", 
        "customer" : {
            "id" : "02d59481-b67d-11e5-f667-b08185e8f6d5", 
            "name" : "", 
            "customer_code" : "WALKIN", 
            "customer_group_id" : "02d59481-b67d-11e5-f667-b08185e893f8", 
            "customer_group_name" : "All Customers", 
            "updated_at" : "2016-01-01 12:16:44", 
            "deleted_at" : "", 
            "balance" : "0", 
            "year_to_date" : "0", 
            "date_of_birth" : "", 
            "sex" : "", 
            "custom_field_1" : "", 
            "custom_field_2" : "", 
            "custom_field_3" : "", 
            "custom_field_4" : "", 
            "note" : "", 
            "contact" : {
            }
        }, 
        "user_id" : "02d59481-b655-11e5-f667-dca974edc4ea", 
        "user_name" : "Alvaro Velosa", 
        "sale_date" : "2018-03-13 20:04:57", 
        "created_at" : "2018-03-13 20:05:08", 
        "updated_at" : "2018-03-13 20:05:08", 
        "total_price" : 3.5, 
        "total_cost" : 2.74, 
        "total_tax" : NumberInt(0), 
        "tax_name" : "No Tax", 
        "note" : "", 
        "status" : "CLOSED", 
        "short_code" : "newa6f", 
        "invoice_number" : "Masonic2107Temple", 
        "accounts_transaction_id" : "", 
        "return_for" : "", 
        "register_sale_products" : [
            {
                "id" : "776a66f2-993c-b372-11e8-26f9cbf10f10", 
                "product_id" : "02dcd191-ae55-11e7-f130-9d4f4bcd91b1", 
                "register_id" : "02dcd191-ae55-11e6-edd8-ec8dce1d9e1c", 
                "sequence" : "0", 
                "handle" : "LAGERDRAUGHT300", 
                "sku" : "10287", 
                "name" : "LAGER DRAUGHT £3.00", 
                "quantity" : NumberInt(1), 
                "price" : 3.5, 
                "cost" : 2.74, 
                "price_set" : NumberInt(0), 
                "discount" : NumberInt(0), 
                "loyalty_value" : NumberInt(0), 
                "tax" : NumberInt(0), 
                "tax_id" : "02d59481-b67d-11e5-f667-b08185ec2871", 
                "tax_name" : "No Tax", 
                "tax_rate" : NumberInt(0), 
                "tax_total" : NumberInt(0), 
                "price_total" : 3.5, 
                "display_retail_price_tax_inclusive" : "0", 
                "status" : "CONFIRMED", 
                "attributes" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "line_note", 
                        "value" : ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ], 
        "totals" : {
            "total_tax" : NumberInt(0), 
            "total_price" : 3.5, 
            "total_payment" : 3.5, 
            "total_to_pay" : NumberInt(0)
        }, 
        "register_sale_payments" : [
            {
                "id" : "776a66f2-993c-b372-11e8-26f9cd75e9aa", 
                "payment_type_id" : "1", 
                "register_id" : "02dcd191-ae55-11e6-edd8-ec8dce1d9e1c", 
                "retailer_payment_type_id" : "02d59481-b655-11e5-f667-b0a23bc0e7bc", 
                "name" : "Cash", 
                "label" : "Account Customer", 
                "payment_date" : "2018-03-13 20:04:57", 
                "amount" : NumberInt(10)
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "776a66f2-993c-b372-11e8-26f9cd7a3096", 
                "payment_type_id" : "1", 
                "register_id" : "02dcd191-ae55-11e6-edd8-ec8dce1d9e1c", 
                "retailer_payment_type_id" : "02d59481-b655-11e5-f667-b0a23bc0e7bc", 
                "name" : "Cash", 
                "label" : "Account Customer", 
                "payment_date" : "2018-03-13 20:04:57", 
                "amount" : -6.5
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample document from the `Vend_raw_transactions` collection which shows the `object_raw_origin_data` field in question and its data?

Comment: Thanks @chridam I've added to original post at the bottom

Comment: I noticed a mistake in my original query but now that I have a name stated, it still isn't into an array. {"object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.register_sale_products.name" AS 'line_items.item_name'} I now have an object called item_name inside of another object called line_items. I need line_items to be an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** operator to shape the field to an array by mapping the array elements to the `item_name` key:

```
"line_items": {
    "$map": {
        "input": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.register_sale_products",
        "as": "product",
        "in": { "item_name": "$$product.name" }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
"line_items" : [ 
    {
        "item_name" : "LAGER DRAUGHT £3.00"
    }
]
```

Comment: thank you for this, that makes total sense and the output is exactly what I want. Currently, I have each field with its own array inside an object called line_items

Comment: and if I want to do more than just the name (quantity, price, id) do I add $map again or comma-delimit more in the "in"?

Comment: don't worry, I tested it out and it works - I add the fields I want into the in {}. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help.